# POST запрос с url на virustotal

Tags: php, javascript, virustotal

Запускаю данный код на локальном сервере Denwer (в php.ini проверял curl не закоментирован)

Сам код который не работает:

```
  $url = array('url' => 'http://vk.com/');
  if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.virustotal.com/ru/url/submission/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
  }
```

Тут я делаю POST запрос с url на virustotal ответ должен быть примерно таким

```
array(sha256: "b2f21cf828ae2d0252af9d764080d6880da…", result: 1, last_analysis_url: "/ru/url/b2f21cf828ae2d0252af9d76408…", timestamp: "1440085831", positives: 1, last_analysis_date: "2015-08-20 15:50:31", total: 63, url_exists: true, first_analysis_date: "2011-11-12 05:35:29", reanalyse_url: "/ru/url/submission/?force=1&url=htt…")
```

Comment: А при чем тут вирустотал?

Comment: А причем тут php? :)

Comment: Ну допустим в php такой фокус можно сделать при помощи curl, если мой талант телепатии правильно распознал цель вопрошающего :)

Comment: Просто есть идея сканировать ссылки через virustotal, да к примеру на curl а и уточню этот POST запрос идет на https://www.virustotal.com/ru/url/submission/

Comment: @tutankhamun, ну зачем же вы своим даром телепатии так разбрасываетесь? :))

Comment: @viktor, сформулируйте нормальный вопрос: укажите что именно вы хотите сделать, приведите пример своего кода, указав что конкретно в нем не работает. Пока ваш вопрос выглядит как "_напишите код за меня_".

Comment: Делаю примерно так   $url = array('url' => 'http://vk.com/');
  if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.virustotal.com/ru/url/submission/');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $url);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
  } но не рабоает ах и делаю все на Denwer curl включен

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает PHP?

Comment: Не каких в скрипте добавляю вверх это ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL); и ошибки 500 тоже нету  Код состояния:  HTTP/2.0 200 OK

Comment: Загрузи свой код в phpStorm, поставь бряку, посмотри на переменные, узнай результат.

Comment: А что такое  phpStorm?

Comment: @DonEladio, не нужно советовать устанавливать проприетарную IDE (которую еще и настраивать надо) чтобы отловить один единственный баг.

Comment: @viktor, вы уверены, что сам запрос отправляется? Что в заголовках ответа `curl`?

Comment: да не знаю какой-то бред не curl не file_get_contents нечего в обще не возвращают

Comment: Значит разбирайтесь с настройками системы. Какие-то проблемы у вас с `curl`. У меня ваш код вполне себе работает (правда выдает `Forbidden`).

Comment: о пере пробовал ещё раз через  file_get_contents заработало ну ладно спасибо помогли чем смогли

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, понимаю что у вас какая-то необоснованная любовь к коммерческим продуктам, но имхо, для новичка, самое-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может надо было использовать опции curl для работы с SSL :

```
// не проверять SSL сертификат
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// не проверять Host SSL сертификата
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
// это необходимо, чтобы cURL не высылал заголовок на ожидание
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
```

Полный пример [здесь](http://www.shkodenko.kiev.ua/index.php?lang_id=1&content_id=165)